# Use of undeclared identifier alloc?

Tags: objective-c, alloc, undeclared-identifier

When I try to create an instance of a custom class, using this code...

```
PlayerTurn *playerTurn = [[alloc] init];
```

...inside the definition of a method in my View Controller `.m` file, I get this error:

> "use of undeclared identifier alloc"

Can someone please explain!? I thought alloc-init was easy.

Comment: `alloc` is a method. It needs to be called on something.

Answer (score 1):

`alloc` is a class method (on effectively all classes). You need to call it on the class you want to create an instance of. So you want :

```
PlayerTurn *playerTurn = [[PlayerTurn alloc] init];
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
PlayerTurn *playerTurn = [[PlayerTurn alloc] init];
```

The [Working with Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html) doc from Apple might be helpful.

Comment: I think I'll go ahead and shoot myself now. You should have an award in this site for most stupid question

Comment: @Dave Too bad there isn't a face-palm Emoji (though there may be one next year).